# VB trying to call function with multiple outputs getting "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[,]' to type 'System.String[,]'." Error

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use a function with multiple outputs (an array and two integers). I thought I had it working but today I am getting an error, "*Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[,]' to type 'System.String[,]'.*"

The function:

```
    Public Function convArray(ByVal inputArray As String(,)) As (outputArray As String(,), outputRows As Integer, outputCol As Integer)
    Dim sColumns As Integer
    Dim sRows As Integer
    Dim AscArray As Boolean


    sRows = inputArray.GetLength(1)
    sColumns = inputArray.GetLength(0)

    Dim outputArray(sColumns - 1, sRows - 1)


    If inputArray(0, 1) > inputArray(0, 2) Then
        AscArray = False
    Else
        AscArray = True
    End If


    For k As Integer = 0 To sColumns - 1
        outputArray(k, 0) = inputArray(k, 0)
    Next

    For i As Integer = 0 To sColumns - 1
        For j As Integer = 1 To sRows - 1
            If AscArray Then
                outputArray(i, j) = inputArray(i, j)
            Else
                outputArray(i, j) = inputArray(i, sRows - j)
            End If

        Next
    Next

    Return (outputArray, sRows, sColumns)

End Function
```

The call:

```
    Dim blrArray = convArray(s)
    sDRows = blrArray.outputRows
    sDColumns = blrArray.outputCol
    ReDim sD(sDColumns - 1, sDRows - 1)
    sD = blrArray.outputArray
```

s and sD are arrays defined elsewhere.

I'm getting the error on the "Return" part of the function.

I apologize in advance for my inefficient code, i'm still pretty new at it.

Comment: You omitted the type declaration (`As String`) on `Dim outputArray(sColumns - 1, sRows - 1)` ; it defaults to `Object`. Enable [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement#to-set-option-strict-in-the-ide), that way the IDE can help prevent these types of errors.

Comment: Life would be easier if you emitted a class.. This *is* OO programming after all, no need to try and shoe everything into a tuple of arrays of objects of strings of tuples of dictionary of array of list of integers...

Comment: TnTinMn, that did the trick!